# Automatically generate a code based on cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just have to input ‘0800’ in column E. It should automatically generate the code in E, should begin with code with ‘ISSICY’ and should get ‘SE’ from 'Sea Export' mentioned in column C and ‘F’ from 'FCL'mentioned in column D. [Screen shot attached of my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWdwX.png) Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?  You can't do this (replace a user-entered value with another value) with a formula - you'd need VBA for this.

Answer (score 2):

First advice I want to give you is: **break down your problem**. I see 3 distinct blocks of that code you want to form , 2 of which I'm sure you can manage yourself. When you have these composite questions, it feels like you're trying to get your homework done and the way you formed your question doesn't make it clear which part you are having troubles with.

Now to get to your question.

```
[ISSICY][SE][0800]
```

I assume your question is about the `[SE]` part, because first block is hard coded and 3rd block is just an increasing number and putting 3 blocks together can be done by concatenating.

I assume what you're trying to do to get the `SE` is **get initial letters of each word in a cell**. I haven't found a native excel way to do it. All of the sources I found require you to write a function of your own and [this article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1658-excel-extract-initials.html) is one of them and it explains the whole process pretty clearly.

Just in case the other link goes down in future here's [another one](http://quadexcel.com/how-to-extract-initials-from-names-in-excel/), with exact same info.

Once you have your function written concatenate each of the 3 blocks and you'll have your result.

Answer (score 0):

I will point you in the right direction. `CONCAT` can be used to concatenate different texts and numbers. You could use

```
=CONCAT(ISSICY",*text from col C*, *text from col d*, "0800") because ISSICY and 0800 is constants.
```

Regarding FCL you could use `LEFT(D1,1)`. Left gets the first *n* characters from the left.

Regarding col c i have insight into how many cases you have in *col c* and therefore cannot give an answer.